# Is there a way to create a search folder on a public folder in outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003, public-folders

I'd like to know if there is a way to create a search folder based on a public folder in outlook 2003?

If not, is there an alternative solution how a similar "view" or function can be archived?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to search the whole public folder you're in just with the "find" button. I do have several public folders and that's how I find what I'm looking for.